# On Linux/Mac, how to start single instance?

Tags: init-file

I just want single instance. I just use a simple .emacs for config, which has

*(use-package server
  :ensure t
  :init
  (server-mode 1)
  :config
  (unless (server-running-p)
    (server-start)))*

It works on MS windows. But on Linux (Ubuntu 18 LTS)/Mac OS, then 2nd instance started with warning:

```
*Warning (server): Unable to start the Emacs server.
There is an existing Emacs server, named "server".
To start the server in this Emacs process, stop the existing
server or call ‘M-x server-force-delete’ to forcibly disconnect it.*
```

May you please give me some suggestion?

Emacs version: 26.2

Answer (score 1):

You only start one emacs with server start.

To start other editors you don't run emacs you run emacsclient which starts a new process running a new frame (a window in OS terms). emacs client connects to the server and uses all the config and state from the server.

Comment: Thanks. Seems "server-running-p" is not working on Linux/Mac but working on Windows. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I just do (server-start) or now `(use-package server
  :ensure nil
  :hook (after-init . server-mode))`

Comment: Thanks. Not working on Ubuntu 18LTS/Emacs 262. Seems emacsclient is the best way